# Code Infinite loop don't know how to stop or fix

Tags: python, for-loop, infinite-loop

Whenever I input choice 3 I loop through the dictionary infinitely but I don't know what's causing it. I want to loop through the dictionary and display the key and values on separate lines once.
Also I can't use break.

```
workerdict = {101:'Fred', 103:'Barney Stone', 106:'Wilma Flint', 109:'Betty Rubble', 112:'Dino Dawg'}

def checkID(id):
    if id in workerdict.keys():
         return True
    return False

def calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage):
    global weeklypay
    weeklypay = (hourWork*hourWage) + overtime
    if hourWork > 40:
        overtime = (hourWork - 40)*(hourWage*1.5)
    return weeklypay

def calculateTax(wage):
    if wage < 300:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.10
    elif wage < 600:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.12
    elif wage < 900:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.15
    elif wage < 1200:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.20
    return wage

def main():
    workerList = []
    idList = []
    overhourlist = []
    overpaylist = []

    print("Choice Options")
    print("\t1. Add Workers")
    print("\t2. Process Worker")
    print("\t3. Display All Workers ID and Name")
    print("\t4. Display Processed Workers")
    print("\t5. End Program")
    print()
    choice = int(input("Input choice: "))

    while choice < 1 or choice > 5:
        choice = int(input("Invalid choice enter a number between 1 and 5, Input choice: "))
    
    while choice != 5:
        if choice == 1:
            workerID = int(input("Enter a worker ID: "))
            if checkID(workerID):
                workerID = int(input("Enter a unused worker ID: "))
                workername = input("Enter the worker name: ")
                workerdict[workerID] = workername

        elif choice == 2:
            workerID = int(input("Enter a worker ID: "))
            if checkID(workerID):
                workerID = int(input("Enter a unused worker ID: "))
                hourWork = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
                if hourWork < 0:
                    print("Enter a valid positive time worked")
                    hourWork = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
                elif hourWage < 0:
                    print("Enter a valid positive wage")
                else:
                    hourWage = int(input("Enter hourly wage: "))
                calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage)
                wage = calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage)
                calculateTax(wage)
                netpay = calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage) - calculateTax(wage)
                worker = str(workerID) + "," + workername + "," + str(calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage))
                workerList.append(worker)
                idList.append(str(workerID))
                if hourWork > 40:
                    overtimehour = hourWork - 40
                overhourlist.append(str(overtimehour))
                overhourlist.append(str(calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage)))
                overtimepay = (hourWork - 40)*(hourWage*1.5)
                overpaylist.append(str(overtimepay))

        elif choice == 3:
            for workerID,workername in workerdict.items():
                print(f"ID: {workerID}, Name: {workername}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Tried fixing it but don't know what's causing it. I don't see anything wrong with indentation I even asked chatgpt but it said indentation. When I take the dictionary and choice 3 into a separate file it doesn't loop but something else is causing it to loop but I don't know what is.

Comment: Your `calculateTax` function is suspitious. You assign values to a new, unused local variable called `Tax`. I think you meant to `return weeklypay * 0.10` and such. Then again, `weeklypay` isn't even defined in that function.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and look for your error.
The problem is that you only choose a number outside your loop. So the variable choice is never updated while inside thus looping infinitely.

In order to fix this, you need to ask the user input inside your loop as well as the check for the user input.

Here is a the quick fix code for you:

```
workerdict = {101:'Fred', 103:'Barney Stone', 106:'Wilma Flint', 109:'Betty Rubble', 112:'Dino Dawg'}

def checkID(id):
    if id in workerdict.keys():
         return True
    return False

def calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage):
    global weeklypay
    weeklypay = (hourWork*hourWage) + overtime
    if hourWork > 40:
        overtime = (hourWork - 40)*(hourWage*1.5)
    return weeklypay

def calculateTax(wage):
    if wage < 300:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.10
    elif wage < 600:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.12
    elif wage < 900:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.15
    elif wage < 1200:
        Tax = weeklypay*0.20
    return wage

def main():
    workerList = []
    idList = []
    overhourlist = []
    overpaylist = []

    print("Choice Options")
    print("\t1. Add Workers")
    print("\t2. Process Worker")
    print("\t3. Display All Workers ID and Name")
    print("\t4. Display Processed Workers")
    print("\t5. End Program")
    print()
    
    choice = 0
    while choice != 5:
        choice = int(input("Input choice: "))
        while choice < 1 or choice > 5:
            choice = int(input("Invalid choice enter a number between 1 and 5, Input choice: "))
        if choice == 1:
            workerID = int(input("Enter a worker ID: "))
            if checkID(workerID):
                workerID = int(input("Enter a unused worker ID: "))
                workername = input("Enter the worker name: ")
                workerdict[workerID] = workername

        elif choice == 2:
            workerID = int(input("Enter a worker ID: "))
            if checkID(workerID):
                workerID = int(input("Enter a unused worker ID: "))
                hourWork = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
                if hourWork < 0:
                    print("Enter a valid positive time worked")
                    hourWork = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
                elif hourWage < 0:
                    print("Enter a valid positive wage")
                else:
                    hourWage = int(input("Enter hourly wage: "))
                calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage)
                wage = calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage)
                calculateTax(wage)
                netpay = calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage) - calculateTax(wage)
                worker = str(workerID) + "," + workername + "," + str(calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage))
                workerList.append(worker)
                idList.append(str(workerID))
                if hourWork > 40:
                    overtimehour = hourWork - 40
                overhourlist.append(str(overtimehour))
                overhourlist.append(str(calculatePay(hourWork,hourWage)))
                overtimepay = (hourWork - 40)*(hourWage*1.5)
                overpaylist.append(str(overtimepay))

        elif choice == 3:
            for workerID,workername in workerdict.items():
                print(f"ID: {workerID}, Name: {workername}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a while loop to execute the action related to a choice.
After you get the choice you just need to execute its action.

You need to remove `while choice != 5:`, unindent the code that was inside of it, and your code will look like this

```
choice = get_choice()
do_action_of_choice(choice)
```

Your code is doing this

```
choice = get_choice()
while choice != 5:
    do_action_of_choice(choice)
```

it keeps doing the action until choice gets changed to 5 but it will never get changed inside the loop so the loop will never stop.

Maybe you meant to give the user a chance to select another choice after an action was executed.

If that's the case you just need to get the choice number inside the `while choice !=5` loop, and your code will look like this

```
choice = -1
while choice != 5:
    choice = get_choice()
    do_action_of_choice(choice)
```

`get_choice()` and `do_action_of_choice()` are just abstractions